# как скрыть ip адрес сервера откуда беру картинки

Tags: php, url, ссылки

Вопрос такой: Есть сервер приложения, там же и картинки к приложению. Делаем сайт для него, и подключаемся к тому серверу за картинками. Хотелось бы скрыть адрес сервера из url

ну то есть вот сейчас примерно вот так в коде src="123.123.123.123:1337/images/abcd.jpg",
а нужно бы полностью скрыть ip.

Знаю что вроде бы можно редирект настроить на php файл через который и будут браться картинки и пользователю будет показывать буд-то картинка находится на сервере этого же сайта, но как то не могу вникнуть как все это сделать правильно.

Или хотя бы заменить ip на более вменяемый адрес

Comment: вот уж что точно не надо - гонять картинки через пхп. редирект внешний можете сделать в хтаксессе, например.

Comment: @teran я вот [тут](http://www.html.by/threads/12543-sprjatat-URL-adres-k-kartinke?p=71771&viewfull=1#post71771) увидел попытку сделать как мне нужно, но работать не хочет.
Плохая идея?

Comment: плохая. Картинки черех пхп имеет смысл выводить только в том случае, когда перед этим следует обработать некоторую логику, например, проверить права доступа или еще его. Чтобы отдать статичный контент пхп не нужен, это не его работа и в целом только лишняя трата ресурсов сервера.